# Drawing Feasible region of a LP with big numbers on constraints

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to draw feasible area of the following LP:

```
\documentclass [11 pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \setbeamercovered{invisible}
    \frametitle{Linear Program}
    \begin{columns}[c]
    \column{0.33\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.01,yscale=0.01][domain=-0.5:5000]
        \draw[->] [very thick] (-0.5,0) -- (5000,0) node[right] {$x_1$};
        \draw[->] [very thick](0,-.5) -- (0,5000) node[above] {$x_2$};
% HERE COMES THE REST OF THE GRAPH
\end{tikzpicture}

\column{0.6\textwidth}
    different piece of code
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem I have is that when I try       `\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-0.5:3500]` It doesn't fit in a slide. Any suggestion to solve this problem?

EDIT: I edited MWE and used `xscale` and `yscale` and I can draw axis but still I get the error `Dimention too large \end{frame}`. Should I simply ignore this? Any thought?

Comment: you can scale the x with `x scale = 0.02` or some small number like that (pass this as another argument after `domain=`). I would really be a good idea to post the code which includes the figure you are trying to draw.

Comment: or use `semilogxaxis` environment.

Comment: In my slightly-sleepy state, I expected to see a picture when I compiled your code :) Could you provide the code for the image too? :)

Comment: @Vivi Thanks for your comments. I updated the question. Any thought? Thanks :-)

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for your comment. I updated the question. Any thought? Thanks :-)

Comment: TikZ by itself can't handle those large values. I would recommend using PGFPlots, which automatically scales the offending values internally, avoiding the error.

Comment: I provided a possible solution, but for future reference, it is much more important to include the code related to your question (ie, the tikz code) than some random code that has nothing to do with your problem (ie, the equations in the array environment).

Comment: @Vivi Thank you for the answer! I put that code just to prevent furture questions like "Why don't you use the whole space in the slide?" etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say if you can't make it, fake it!

You can use values that are 1/1000 smaller than the values you need, and then pretend that the values are bigger when labelling the axes. Have a look at my example:

```
\documentclass [11 pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \setbeamercovered{invisible}
    \frametitle{Linear Program}

    \begin{columns}[c]
        \column{0.33\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \draw[->] [very thick] (-0.5,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x_1$};
            \draw[->] [very thick](0,-.5) -- (0,5) node[above] {$x_2$};
            % Tick marks and labels on the axes
            \foreach \x in {1, 2, 3, 4 } {
                \draw (\x,0)+(90:0.1cm) -- (\x,0) node[below]{\scriptsize $\x 000$};
                \draw (0,\x)+(0:0.1cm) -- (0,\x) node[left]{\scriptsize $\x 000$};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \column{0.6\textwidth}
        different piece of code
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If this doesn't solve your problem, you need to show us your full tikz code. Without that it is hard to give you alternative ways to solve the problem. As Jake said in a comment, `pgfplots` can deal with larger numbers, and with your full code it wouldn't be hard to transform it into a `pgfplots` figure.